# IF OR Function in jQuery on a PHP site

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement

Can anyone tell me what's wrong and how to fix this bit of code...

I am trying to bring up a message and not go to the next page, if the `#send_country` box has either **nothing** in it or says `"Send From..."` (as its the placeholder).

This is the bit of code I am having issues with:

```
if (country == '0' || country == "Send From...") {
    error = 1;
    jQuery('.msg').text("Please Select A Country.");
}
```

I think I have an issue with the OR function as it works without the `|| country == "Send From..."`.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.submit').click(function() {

            var error = 0;
            var country = jQuery('#send_country').val();
            var countrys = jQuery('#delv_country').val();
            var idsa = jQuery('.size').val();

            if (country == '0' || country == "Send From...") {
                error = 1;
                jQuery('.msg').text("Select A Country.");
            }
            if (countrys == '0') {
                error = 1;
                jQuery('.msg').text("Select A Country.");
            }

            if (error) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the #send_country box has either nothing in it or says "Send From..." (as its the placeholder).

The `placeholder` attribute is different than the `value`, you couldn't get the `placeholder` using `.val();` instead you should use `.prop('placeholder')` :

```
var country_placeholder = jQuery('#send_country').prop('placeholder');
```

So the condition will be :

```
if (country == '0' || country_placeholder == "Send From...") {
```

But like this the condition will always return true since the placeholder will not change if you're filling the field, so i suggest just to check if the value is empty or '0' :

```
if (country == '0' || country == "") {
```

Hope this helps.

```js
jQuery('.submit').click(function() {
  var error = 0;
  var country = jQuery('#send_country option:selected').val();

  if (country == '') {
    error = 1;
    jQuery('.msg').text("Select A Country.");
  }

  if (error) {
    console.log('EROOR');
  } else {
    console.log('SUBMIT');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select type="text" id='send_country'>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Send From...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>

  <button class='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>

<span class='msg'></span>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have made this my first option  <option value="" disabled selected>Send From...</option> as the placeholder as I am having trouble, can I just make it see the "Send From..." in the or statement?

Comment: I think i got you, the problem is in the way you're retrieving the value of the select, use `var country = jQuery('#send_country option:selected').val();`. (check my updated snippet).